# Losing path dependent type when extracting value from Try in scala

Tags: scala, try-catch

I'm working with `scalax` to generate a graph of my Spark operationS. So, I have a custom library that generates my graph. So, let me show a sample:

```scala
val DAGWithoutGet = createGraphFromOps(ops)
val DAGWithGet = createGraphFromOps(ops).get
```

The return type of `DAGWithoutGet` is

`scala.util.Try[scalax.collection.Graph[typeA, scalax.collection.GraphEdge.DiEdge]]`,

and, for `DAGWithGet` is 
`scalax.collection.Graph[typeA, scalax.collection.GraphEdge.DiEdge]`.

Here, `typeA` is a project related class representing a single Spark operation, not relevant for the context of this question. (for context only: What my custom library does is, essentially, generate a map of dependencies between those operations, creating a big Map object, and calling `Graph(myBigMap: _*)` to generate the graph).

As far as I know, calling the `.get` command on this point of my code or later should not make any difference, but that is not what I'm seeing. 
Calling `DAGWithoutGet.get.nodes` has a return type of `scalax.collection.Graph[typeA,DiEdge]#NodeSetT`, 
while calling `DAGWithGet.nodes` returns `DAGWithGet.NodeSetT`.

When I extract one of those nodes (using the `.find` method), I receive `scalax.collection.Graph[typeA,DiEdge]#NodeT` and `DAGWithGet.NodeT` types, respectively. Much to my dismay, even the methods available in each case are different - I cannot use `pathTo` (which happens to be what I want) or `withSubgraph` on the former, only on the latter.

My doubt is, then, after this relatively complex example: what is going on here? Why extracting the value from the `Try` construct on different moments leads to different types, one path dependent, and the other not - or, if that isn't correct, what may I be missing here?

Comment: `x.f().g()` is different from `val v = x.f(); v.g()` when inferring dependent types. It looks like `nodes` returns a type that is a `v.NodeSet` or similar, not a `w.NodeSet` for a different graph value. The `val v` is a stable value.

Comment: FIrst thing, I didn't know about that first statement. Being a functional language and all, I assumed those expressions would result in just the same thing. Can you recommend something for me to read on that matter? Also, do you understand why is the returned type called `myVar.NodeT`? I really can't grasp that. What you said makes sense, but I'm still at a loss about how to convert one type to another, and the doc, imo, is terrible...

Comment: Well, at least I got one part of it. The concept I didn't know was path dependent types, and that is part of what is going on here. The question, then. becomes, why using a Try statement makes me lose the path dependent type I get without it,

Comment: The difference is the chained method invocations. Cf https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5999 for a different look at why it matters. I took a quick look at the code base and saw some downcasts to the "current" node type, so maybe you're supposed to use that API for your use case. Maybe ask on their forum.

Comment: Mailing list, that would be - more precisely, a google group. Seems pretty quiet, though.- gonna try that regardless. Thanks for the reference. Could you try to pull together an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: I didn't really answer your question. There must be a general answer somewhere, and a specific answer for your API. I see some Q&A use Graph#Node examples.